# Are Hibernate and RDLC alternatives to each other?

Tags: hibernate, orm, rdlc

I know Hibernate is an ORM, I'm not familiar with RDLC, is it an ORM as well?  If they are both ORMs wouldn't it make sense for an application team to choose to use one rather than the other during development (as opposed to using both)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, ORMs are for pulling data from a relational database and using it to populate objects that the application uses, RDLC is a tool for creating reports. They are two different things and you could easily use both in one application.